# How do I use generic base class instead of window in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, generics, inheritance

How do I make this work?

```
public partial class MyWindow : View<MyViewModel>
{
}
```

where View is defined as

```
public class View<T> : Window where T : IViewModel, new()
{
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:View
x:Class="Project.MyWindow"
x:TypeArguments="ViewModels:MyViewModel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Mynamespace.ViewModels;assembly=Mynamespace.ViewModels"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
>
```

I get this error... The name View does not exist in the namespace Project... which of course it does.

and I get this error which really confuses me... The property "TypeArguments" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" namespace... which of course it does.

Any clues on how to use generics as a base class for windows in wpf?

Comment: Don't make your Views generic. Make your ViewModels generic. What do you want that for?

Comment: I'm trying to not replicate code. For each window in our application (and there are many) each window looks the same... MyWindow:Window { T vm = new T(); ctor() { this.InitializeComponent(); vm.CloseRequest += (sender, e) => this.Close(); this.DataContext = vm; } }   ... seems like the easiest thing to do is make a generic base class that simply takes the viewmodel type in. I will admit I am a newbie in many ways. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Your approach seems to be ok. At least I can compile it without problems. Did you try to rebuild all or perhaps restart Visual Studio?

Comment: @PriceJones XAML + generics will make your life hell.  Better to live with a bit of code replication (imo).

Comment: @HighCore & pricejones Incorrect. [PageFunction<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615540(v=vs.110).aspx). See  [Structured Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741843(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MickyDuncan Does this work for windows as well as pages?

Comment: @PriceJones Yes indeedy http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37317/Generic-Support-In-XAML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question is to never use generics with xaml. There is always a better way or a workaround. See the comments on the original post.

EDIT!

Thanks to Micky Duncan (see the comments above) the correct answer to this question can be found by investigating these two links:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741843(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741843%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37317/Generic-Support-In-XAML

Comment: -1 Incorrect. [PageFunction<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615540(v=vs.110).aspx). See  [Structured Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741843(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: the first link to msdn article is down. Do you have a replacement?

Comment: @GGirard if you go to the first link and change the target framework from 4.5 to 3.0 the article will appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Old Topic, but as I came around and others might to:
I don't know since when, but tested in .net 6.0

The approach was right, but without knowing which project settings the questioner used it is hard to say what went wrong.

*yes i know it's ugly, but i have to admit is was a prove of concept prototyp*

### SAMPLE XAML:

```
<base:ApplicationTabItem x:TypeArguments="entries:ArtikelEntry,vms:ArtikelTabViewModel"
    x:Class="S2_Management.DesktopApp.UIElements.AppTabs.ArtikelTab"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:S2_Management.DesktopApp.UIElements.AppTabs"
                    mc:Ignorable="d" 
                    xmlns:vms ="clr-namespace:S2_Management.DesktopApp.ViewModels"
                    xmlns:values="clr-namespace:S2_Management.CoreLib.ConstantValues;assembly=S2-Management.CoreLib"
                    xmlns:entries="clr-namespace:S2_Management.CoreLib.Tables;assembly=S2-Management.CoreLib"
                    xmlns:base="clr-namespace:S2_Management.DesktopApp.UIElements.Base"
                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vms:ArtikelTabViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}"
                    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
                    >
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Label Content="{Binding FQ_TabName}"/>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Grid KeyUp="OnKeyUp">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemListe}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ItemDoubleClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static values:ConstantValueStore.ArtikelTabGridBezeichnungTitle}" Binding="{Binding Artikel_Bezeichnung}" IsReadOnly="True" SortDirection="Ascending" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static values:ConstantValueStore.ArtikelTabGridEinheitenTitle}" Binding="{Binding Einheit.Einheiten_Bezeichnung}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static values:ConstantValueStore.ArtikelTabGridKategorieTitle}" Binding="{Binding ArtikelKategorie.ArtikelKategorien_Bezeichnung}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static values:ConstantValueStore.ArtikelTabGridPreisGruppeTitle}" Binding="{Binding Preisgruppe.Preisgruppen_Bezeichnung}" IsReadOnly="True"/>


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</base:ApplicationTabItem>
```

### Sample CodeBehind

```cs
namespace S2_Management.DesktopApp.UIElements.AppTabs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// logic for ArtikelTab.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ArtikelTab //: ApplicationTabItem<ArtikelEntry, ArtikelTabViewModel>
    {

        public ArtikelTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = _vm = getTabViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

### Sample BaseClass:

```cs
namespace S2_Management.DesktopApp.UIElements.Base
{
    public class ApplicationTabItem<ItemType, TVMType> : TabItem, IApplicationTabItem
        where TVMType : ITabViewModel<ItemType>, new()
    {
        protected TVMType? _vm;

        protected TVMType getTabViewModel()
        {
            return new TVMType() { OwnTabItem = this };
        }

        public virtual RibbonTab? GetRibbonTab()
        {
            return _vm?.GetRibbonTab();
        }

        protected void ItemDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs? e)
        {
            _vm?.OpenSelectedItemFor(CRUDModus.Read);
        }

        protected void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0)
            {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.D:
                        _vm?.CopyCommand?.Execute(null);
                        break;
                    case Key.N:
                        _vm?.CreateNewCommand?.Execute(null);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.Escape:
                        if (_vm != null) _vm.SelectedItem = default;
                        break;
                    case Key.Enter:
                        ItemDoubleClick(this, null);
                        break;
                    case Key.Delete:
                    case Key.Back:
                        _vm?.DeleteCommand?.Execute(null);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

### Explanation

```cs
 public class ApplicationTabItem<ItemType, TVMType> : TabItem, IApplicationTabItem
        where TVMType : ITabViewModel<ItemType>, new()
```

This is the superclass, which inherits from TabItem. As we all, should, know:

```
TabItem
```

is an UIElement and brings everything we need!

```
<base:ApplicationTabItem x:TypeArguments="entries:ArtikelEntry,vms:ArtikelTabViewModel"
```

is what say's hey inherit please!

### IMPORTANT:

```cs
public partial class ArtikelTab //: ApplicationTabItem<ArtikelEntry, ArtikelTabViewModel>
```

Original we could inherit in code behind as well, which is :

1. redundant
2. Bad style, because you need to change things on two places
3. **but: better and faster readable**

but as of today there is an open BUG:

**Inheriting from a generic type within a code behind file will fail during the [whatever].xaml.g.s generation. So be VERY sure to remove that inherit from code behind, or at leased put it on comment!!!**

Link to MS Blog Page on that topic, but in a very early state of support:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/limited-generics-support-in-xaml